# Angular reactive form, confirm email is not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular reactive forms. I implemented email and confirm email. Email input is working as per expected but confirm email is not. Below is the link to stackblitz. I am not able to find where I am doing some mistake

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-yzp92p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: What does "not working" means exactly ?

Comment: I did coding if confirm email doesnt match, but its not shwoing up

Comment: In order to call your onSubmit () method, you need to add type="submit" to your submit button

Comment: I added but its not working yet

Comment: I saw that you made type = onSubmit () but you have to write type="submit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validator object is defined relative to the `userData` FormGroup, not the overall `signupForm`. This means the `emailMismatch` error will live on the `userData` object - you are checking `signupForm`.

This is your original code:

```
get isEmailMismatch() { 
    return this.signupForm.getError('emailMismatch');
}
```

It should be:

```
get isEmailMismatch() {
    return this.signupForm.controls.userData.getError('emailMismatch');
}
```

Note we went one level deeper here (to `userData`) to find the error.

Working stackblitz --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-4ypbn5?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

This is the edited working code on [stackblitz](https://angular-email-checker-yzm2np.stackblitz.io/)

Your validators are working fine.
 You just need to add `type="submit"` to your submit button